# Any menu or hotkey to quickly comment/uncomment code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Any quick way to comment/uncomment java source code in Eclipse?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> toggles C-style comments.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> toggles single-line comments.

Answer (score 4):

**For Multiline Comments:**

Comment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
Uncomment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

**For Single Line Comments:**

Comment/Uncomment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>